# Adobe Illustrator Error - Hover/click area of object is dislocated from the object itself

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selection

I feel like im taking crazy pills. I can't select particular objects as their hover/click areas appear to be dislocated from the objects themselves. Im using iOS 10.14 with Illustrator 23.0.6.
[This video displays what it happening](https://www.dropbox.com/s/50cdxmku4xwa9lc/illustrator-hover-click-glitch.mov?dl=0). 
I've closed Illustrator and restarted my comp. Any suggestions?